# Is it possible to have multiple partials for a record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

I have tables of reviews, venues and users.

I currently have a _review.html.erb partial which displays reviews for a venue on the venues show page.

Is it possible to have another partial called _profile_review.html.erb and have it display all the reviews written by a user in the users show page?

I want to have 2 differant partials for reviews so I can style each differantly.

Thanks very much for any help its much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware that you can pass any variables to a partial using the :locals option?

```
render :partial => "whatever", :locals => {:foo => bar}
# bar is available as local variable foo within _whatever.erb
```

Btw. if you want to make some local variables optional you can use the following trick to avoid a 'no such variable' error:

```
- optional_variable ||= nil # defines optional_variable without overwriting it
```

I think using this you should be able to do whatever you can imagine :).

Comment: @retro, thanks for the answer that link is helping alot but i'm stuck with why this bit of code wont work: <%= render :partial => 'reviews/review', :collection => @user.reviews, :locals => { :review => profiles } %> I thought it would render the partial called _profile but its giving a "undefined local variable or method `profiles'" error

Comment: I never use the @collection, as its too magic. I suggest you instead do `<% @user.reviews.each do |review| %><%= render "reviews/review", :profile => review %><% end %>`.

Comment: you'll note this is a different syntax, stating the partial's path, and any local variables as the next argument. For the :locals argument, you specify the name of the variable, then the value.

Comment: btw. take a brief look at haml.. :) it's just soo much more fun (or less pain)

Comment: @Matthew Rudy, thanks for the answer, its still trying to render the _review partial though, changing it to <%= render "reviews/profile" %> renders the _profile partial for each review record but gives a "undefined local variable or method `review'" error when entering something like <%= review.title %> to the _profile partial

Comment: if you use the style like I showed `<%= render "reviews/profile", :profile => review %> it will set the "profile" variable locally to the value of "review"

Comment: @Matthew Rudy, sorry I was struggling to follow, its working now! Thanks very much